# Difference between git clean and system rm

Tags: git

What is the difference between:

```
git clean -f temp1.txt
```

and

```
rm temp1.txt
```

Git doc says:

`git-clean` - Remove untracked files from the working tree

So what is really the point of doing this instead of only the system command?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`rm` will delete the file no matter what. `git-clean` will only delete it if it's actually untracked. And of course `git-clean` also accepts arguments that customize its behavior in a repo-aware manner (e.g. `-x`).

Comment: I wish I could Accept ALL the answers you guys made. Thank you all, your explanations really helped me :]

Answer (score 7):

For your example?  No difference at all.  `git clean` is convenient when you have a lot of untracked files that you want to delete without having to figure out where they all are by yourself.  It has the recursion built in, an understanding of which files are tracked and which files aren't, and even handles ignored files properly.

Answer (score 6):

The big advantage of [`git clean`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) comes when specifying no path, or a path that applies to multiple files. If you just run `git clean -xdf` you basically restore the working directory to the original state without any untracked files. For example when you have generated binary files ignored, you can use it to remove them all at once, without having to specify each folder manually.